# Txt parsing to 2D array and converting float

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, floating-point

```
#include<string.h>
#define ROW 1000
#define COL 1000"

int main(){
   char* pend;
 FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
 if(fp == NULL){
   printf("File error");
   return 0;
 }
 else{

 float matris[1000][1000] ;
 char buffer[100];
 char* ptr1;
 char* ptr2;

 while(fgets(buffer,10000,fp)){
   //printf("aa");
   ptr1 = strtok(buffer,"\n");
   ptr2 = strtok(ptr1,",");

   while(ptr2!=NULL){
     printf("%s ",ptr2);
     ptr2=strtok(NULL,",");
     float f1 = strtof(ptr2, &pend); 
     float f2 = strtof(pend, NULL);
     matris[0][0] = f1[0];
     printf("%f",matris[0][0]);

   }
   //printf("%s",ptr2);
   printf("\n");
 }}
 return 0;
}
```

the output of printf("%s ",ptr2); is that 
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 0(new line)
4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 0(new line)
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 0(new line)
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 0

and the txt file 
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0(new line)
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,0(new line)
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,0(new line)
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,0

I wanna put them to 2D array like matris[0][0] = 5.1 matris[0][1] = 3.5 matris[1][0] = 4.9 as a float number.

What can I do ? İf you know can you implement that to my code ?

Comment: you are not indexing the arrays in your loop. Instead of while, use for(i for one loop and for(j for the second then you do matris[i][j]

Comment: I have tried there for just an example and      matris[0][0] = f1[0];
is not working I dont know how to use the return value of strtof(pend, NULL);

Comment: its because you declare f1 as a float - float f1 = strtof(ptr2, &pend); then you use it as an array: matris[0][0] = f1[0]; it should just be matris[0][0] = f1;

Comment: `f1[0]` is not valid C Just do `matris[0][0] = f1; matrix[0][1] = f2;` (if that works, replace it by two nested loops so you don't need to write this for every entry)